# Compiling vim with xterm_clipboard support

Tags: vim, xorg, clipboard, xterm

I checked out latest vim7 from cvs repository.

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@vim.cvs.sf.net:/cvsroot/vim checkout vim7
```

I tried:

`./configure --enable-xterm_clipboard`

but I got -

`WARNING: unrecognized options --enable-xterm_clipboard`

I tried:

`./configure --with-x`

but I got -

`configure: error: unrecognized option: --with_x`.

Can someone please tell me the correct way to configure with xterm_clipboard support?

### Edit

I tried `./configure --with-feature=normal --with-x --with-gui` in the `src` directory, but got `WARNING: unrecognized options --with-feature, --with-gui` at the end.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11416069/5951320

Answer (score 9, accepted):

by looking at `src/feature.h` you can see that:

```
#ifdef FEAT_GUI
# ifndef FEAT_CLIPBOARD
#  define FEAT_CLIPBOARD
#  ifndef FEAT_VISUAL
#   define FEAT_VISUAL
#  endif
# endif
#endif

#if defined(FEAT_NORMAL) && defined(FEAT_VISUAL) \
    && (defined(UNIX) || defined(VMS)) \
    && defined(WANT_X11) && defined(HAVE_X11)
# define FEAT_XCLIPBOARD
# ifndef FEAT_CLIPBOARD
#  define FEAT_CLIPBOARD
# endif
#endif
```

- having `--with-features=normal`
- having `--enable-gui`
- having `--with-x`

you should get your `xterm-clipboard`

Comment: works flawless on my server right now.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. However as I said, `--with-x` is giving error at top level, `--with-feature`, `--with-gui` are giving error if I run configure in src directory.

Comment: are you doing configure at top level?

Comment: yes. cvs yada yada; cd vim7; ./configure --with-x

Comment: argh :(. Doesn't work for me. I suppose you checked out same version as me `cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@vim.cvs.sf.net:/cvsroot/vim checkout vim7`.  Thanks for the help though

Comment: did you notice i fixed --with-feature*s* and --enable-gui (instead of --with-gui)?

Comment: Indeed I did not :). This works now!

Comment: `--with-features=normal` is default, and doesn't need to be set. Using `--with-features=big` or `--with-features=huge` will include all of the "normal" features too.

Answer (score 8):

To easiest way to get vim working with `xterm_clipboard` is:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: is this just for Ubuntu?

Comment: This enables support for `xterm_clipboard` also for the console version of `vim` (on Ubuntu systems).

Comment: on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the package name for the visual component of vim is 'vim-gui-common'

Comment: `vim-gui-common` works perfectly in Ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu, the flags above worked for me, but I also had to install the `xorg-dev` package

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev

./configure --with-x --enable-gui=auto  --with-features=huge
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't running configure in the src directory, but rather one level up.  If you do `chdir src; configure --with-x` it should work okay.

But keep in mind two points:

1. With Vim, the preferred way of modifying configure options is to modify src/Makefile
2. The default is to enable the GUI, and thus +xterm_clipboard, and as far as I know you can't have +xterm_clipboard without the GUI being compiled in.

Comment: Yes, indeed I was running it at top level as usually thats recommended. I will try in src directory. (and also see the Makefile - I don't know changes there are preferred for vim).

Comment: @Heptite: you can have clipboard without the gui, all you need is X. folks working mostly in xterm would be very unhappy otherwise :)

Comment: @akira: I have edited my post to clarify my statement: I believe you must have a GUI compiled in to have the +xterm_clipboard feature available.

Comment: your statement was clear, and i thought mine was clear as well: you do not need --enable-gui to have +xterm_clipboard: here, selfcompiled seconds ago: "VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jan 21 2011 08:17:30) ... Normal version without GUI. ...  +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save". all thats needed to have +xterm_clipboad is './configure --with-x --with-features=normal'

Comment: Ah, I stand (sit) corrected.  It's been a long time since I've bothered to compile Vim without a GUI.

Comment: @Heptite: this was the first time ever i compiled vim myself. for such nonsense binary packages exists :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution.
I like to copy and paste over the clipboard with vim(very nice for copy between two remote vim session)
Most distro don't compile vim with clipboard support(slackware for example) but compile gvim with clipboard support(slackware again).
So simply use gvim,after edit .vimrc with this line(if you want like me to copy over vim)

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

And for console without x or for people who don't like gui?

```
gvim -v
```